# принадлежность переменной к списку в Python

Tags: python

есть функция:

```
def checkSomething(var,varList):
    if var in varList:
        doSomeStuff()
    else:
        print("error")
```

передаваемые значения таковы, что ветка else не должна выполняться(например, var=354, varList=[123,321,354]). Вывод переданных значений перед проверкой условия это подтверждает, однако каким-то непостижимым образом выполняется ветка else.

при этом если попробовать то же самое запустить в командной строке(без всяких фреймворков и библиотек) то все работает как надо(т.е. else не выполняется)

вопрос в том, как такое вообще возможно и как этого избежать?

Comment: Этот код правильный (пример: `checkSomething(1, [1, 2, 3])`, `checkSomething('1', '1,2,3')`). Покажите тот, в котором проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в общем я сам дурак, проблема была в том, что var на самом деле был не int (как я считал), а unicode

Answer (score 1):

```
var = 354
varList = [123,321,354]
def checkSomething(var,varList):
    if var in varList:
        print('dosomeStuff')
    else:
        print("error")

checkSomething(354,[123,321,354])
```

Вот этот код работает прекрастно.

Comment: Инициализация var и varList не нужна

Comment: ... и код по сути не отличается от того, что автор привел в вопросе :)